# Can I turn a mac template to android template?

Tags: android, ios

I created a mac template for a game i was making, I get almost all the way done and my mac crashes. well I saved the template and ended up getting a windows 8. is there anyway I can take what I have and open it in android studio? I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "template"? Do you mean a .xib file or something?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Virtual Machine (VM) with OS X. Then import it in that OS.

You can get more informations about how to set up Windows VMs for OS X on:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj945426.asp

http://www.sysprobs.com/working-os-x-10-9-mavericks-vmware-image-for-windows-os-intel-processor